# "to hit one's funny bone"

Tags: single-word-request

Was sagt man auf Deutsch, wenn man *hits one's funny bone* (den Nerv am Ellenbogen)?

Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Musikantenknochen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nervus_ulnaris) ist das Wort / der Begriff, den du suchst.

Siehe auch: [wiktionar](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Musikantenknochen)y.

---

Der Wikipedia-Artikel listet auch noch Begriffe auf, die ich nicht kannte:

- „Musikknochen“
- „Musikantenknochen“
- „Musikerknochen“
- „Mäuschen/Mäusle“

regional:

- Saarland: „geggisch Oder“
- Österreich: „narrisches Bein“, „narrisches Band’l“ oder „damisches Aderle“
- Schweiz: „Narrenbein“, „Surribei“ oder „Surrbeindli“

Comment: Ah ja, ich sehe den Satz "Ich habe mir den Musikantenknochen angeschlagen." Vielen Dank, choXer! Eine Kollegin sagte neulich something like "Autsch! Es hat mir eine gegeben." (oder etwas in der Art). Sie rieb an ihrem Ellenbogen und meinte höchstwahrscheinlich, dass der Schmerz sich wie ein elektrischer Schlag anfühlt. Ich habe jedoch nicht verstanden, "eine" was? und ich traute mich nicht nachzufragen. Habe ich sie missverstanden oder sagt man tatsächlich so?

Comment: @Serena Frag gerne einfach bei deiner Kollegin nach, wenn du etwas nicht verstehst. Die meisten werden dir gerne weiterhelfen.
Ich vermute, dass sie mit "eine" "eine Schelle" meinte. "Eine gegeben" ist tatsächlich relativ häufig und man lässt "die Schelle" normalerweise weg und spricht das nicht.

Comment: Ich kenne nur "Musikknochen"; vermutlich nord-deutsche Variante?

Comment: voll auf den Musikknochen!